# How to convert HtmlPage into Html string in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I want to convert a page into a real HTML string, with `<html>`, `<body>`, etc..., not XML. I only see the `asXml()` function, which often changes many things in the structure.

Also note that I've performed modifications to the page after fetching it and I want those modifications to be present in the output as well.

How can I do that? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me check if I got it right:

1. You fetched a page
2. You performed modifications to the page (EG: modifying nodes in it)
3. You want a valid HTML page containing the previous modifications as a String

`page.asXml()` will not help. This will return a valid XML file as a String rather than a valid HTML file.

`page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()` will not help either. This will returned the response that the server gave you as it is (without any modification that you have made).

There is no other method that would return a string with a valid HTML String.

However, you could try using `page.save(file)`. That would save the page the modified page to a file as HTML. Sadly, I don't think there is a method that receives an `OutputStream` so you're most likely to have to save the file to a file system and then get it back.

Probably, you could take a look at the HTMLUnit source and see how that method is implemented. Maybe adding your own `save` method is not that complex :)

Comment: OK, maybe I'll use your way. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: IMO, page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString() might work in this situation. He wants to get raw HTML returned by the host (even without changes made by Javascript rendering stuff)

Comment: @MinhLe Due to the low reputation you are not able to see se a deleted answer. In it, there is a comment from the OP that rejects it stating: `No, because I've modified something, so I want to return it. This function just returns the file without my modification. –  Forte_201092`. That's why I clarified what the OP wants in my answer :)

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho: ahhh, got it, thanks for clarification. We should edit his question to make sure people understand the problem he has got. :-P